# Android library written in Kotlin, provide support for Java apps

Tags: java, android, kotlin, language-interoperability

I am writing an Android library in Kotlin. But when used in Android apps written in Java the support is very poor. For example default parameters in Kotlin are still required in Java. Another one is, non-null parameters does not accept null in Kotlin app (compile time error) but throws run time exception when `null` is passed in Java. I know about null checks but they make the code look dirty.

What is the proper way to support Android Java apps? Direction, suggestions, examples are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function has default arguments you can use the `@JvmOverloads` annotation to create separate methods for Java users. There are also more similar enhancements to Java support in Kotlin. [Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html) is a list what you can do.

You can also use `@Nullable` and `@NotNull` annotations on local variables and fields to improve IDE support for nullable values (also more likely the compiler will fail at compile time rather than runtime).

IntelliJ Idea auto generates not `null` checks for you when you use the `@NotNull` annotation.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions. Is there some compilation of such practices?

Comment: @Ryan Added a link to my answer. have a look at it